# Deployer laravel recipe and blade templating deploy issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, php-deployer

I am trying to setup deploy using Deployer with laravel recipe

my `deploy.php` is without any customisations just with:

`require 'vendor/deployer/deployer/recipe/laravel.php'` and `host` configuration.

Unfortunately I have issue with templating. Every time I deploy new version it uses template from first version `releases/1` (no matter how many version I deploy).

Nothing what I found so far helps (I tried different configurations of `deploy.php` from internet but nothing works for me.)

(`artisan view:clear` and `artisan cache:clear` recipe has)

Thanks for any advices!

Comment: have you tried `composer dump-autoload` ?

Comment: Thank you for response @JamesRiady! I tried but did not help. :( I found out the problem is only with template, styles are compiled and applied properly. It will be something weird, when I delete all older releases from `releases` folder (2, 3, 4, ...) and leave there only last one (the same `current` points to), everything works correctly.